# Not able to fetch precise double value

Tags: java, jdbc

```java
@Column(name="tax-rate)
Public Double taxRate;
```

For above column in particular table, I am not able to get precise value.
Actual value in database = 5.0004
Value I am getting during execution= 5.0

How can I get precise 5.0004 value ?

I tried to use `BigDecimal` but still not able to fetch precise value.

Comment: Are you using [Spring](https://spring.io/)?

Comment: Doubles don't have a precise value.